# C# callbacks not working

Tags: c#, .net

I'm defining a function that takes another function as a parameter (using Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler version 8.00.50727.4927) but I get a weird error.

Here's the function definition:

```
public ManagementScope ConnectComputerWMI(string computerName, 
    string username, string password, 
    Action callbackProcessEnd) {... }
```

And here's the error:

```
error CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires '1' type arguments
```

I'm not sure what type System.Action needs.

Comment: How are you calling this function? Can you post that and the definition of the passed in `Action`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message makes it look like it doesn't know about the non-generic `Action` delegate, and the only reason I can think of for that is that you're targeting .NET 2.0. In .NET 2.0, only `Action<T>` existed; more versions were introduced in .NET 3.5, and even more in .NET 4.

EDIT: I've just seen that you're using Visual Studio 2005 - which means you *are* targeting .NET 2.0. (Did you have a previous version of the question which specified .NET 4? I could have sworn you did...)

That's the problem... now there are various solutions. You *could* declare your own delegate:

```
public delegate void Action();
```

Or you *could* use [`MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) or (which has an equivalent signature, but is unfortunately in the Windows Forms namespace - not ideal if you're not using Windows Forms)...

Or you could upgrade to a more modern version of Visual Studio and .NET.

Comment: +1 - you are probably right: *"using Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler"*. Side note: `System.Action` was introduced in .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Fredrik: I think that was added later... I could have sworn it initially said .NET 4.

Comment: @Jon: it's present in the 3.5 documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @Fredrik: Yes, it was introduced in .NET 3.5. My point is that the *question* originally claimed he was using .NET 4, I believe.

Comment: Action<T> was introduced in 2.0. But Action in 3.5.

Comment: @Jon: Ah, now I get it. Makes sense now (even to me) :)